# Htaccess how to not redirect specific files and folders

Tags: ajax, apache, .htaccess

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/*|ajax|portal/*|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now i want to exclude the assets folder the portal folder and all ajax calls. But still all of these files are redirected when i look into the network tab.

Im not very familiar with apache2 and the htaccess configuration.

How can i make this work?

I have tried looking into the docs to fix to problem however it keeps occuring and don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: "redirected when i look into the **network tab**" - The only external redirect in the code you've posted is the www to non-www canonical redirect (first rule). You should already be linking to the canonical URL, so that should not be an issue. You've added your exception to the second rule - which is an internal rewrite and would not trigger an external redirect viewable in the "network tab". (?) Your regex is a bit wrong, but it would still "work". How do you identify "ajax calls"? (Any request that starts "ajax"?) What exactly are you seeing in the "network tab"?

Comment: Thanks for your response. First of all, I thought it was because of my .htaccess file however I found the problem came from elsewhere. I am using PHPAuth, a library for managing login etc... I have a middleware class that checks if the user is logged in. So for every request, I make it checks if I'm logged in or not, so the request gets redirected there, however it's still weird behavior because the session cookie is send with it and should validate it, but it doesn't.

Comment: "for every request" - Only for requests passed to your front-controller (`index.php`) and your rule in `.htaccess` would seem to already exclude the requests as mentioned? (I'm assuming you don't have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?)

Comment: Above rules are the only i have in my .htaccess. The problem occurs occasionally because of my middleware class that checks is I'm logged in see: https://imgur.com/a/mHZ0Hm3 . Some ajax calls are redirected and even my CSS stylesheets, when the session cookie is present.. https://imgur.com/a/DPYGa5u. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and how this error occurs, sometimes it works fine and then it doesn't. btw on localhost is it all working fine but on a remote server it itsn't.